# Is there a way to show desktop notifications even if Chrome closed?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extenstion, I wonder if there is anyway to show desktop notifications even if Chrome is closed, maybe some sort of background process or service? Kindly advice and guide me if it is not possible also. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you request a ["background"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) permission your extension's background page will be able to show notifications even with Chrome windows closed.

> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

Answer (score -3):

If you use Google Chrome, you can enable a new Gmail feature that shows desktop notifications for new messages. Go to "Settings", and enable chat notifications and mail notifications to see a small bubble when you get a new message.

Secondly: Using WCF or Windows Services:

you have to develop simple client on  machine polling a central service for alerts. Each alert should have a unique id so each client can deal with idem-potency

I Hope that this will be helpfull to you
Regards: Azeem Raavi

Comment: I'm talking about Google Chrome Extensions.