# can a google chrome extension flash an OS style alert?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

for example, growl flashes a message in the upper right corner regardless of which application is running.  Skype makes the icon in the dock have a little red dot with a number of new messages.  Is there anyway to write a chrome extension to have this type of functionality?  that is, I want to write a chat system that works in the browser but also notifies users when they have closed my site's tab, or even when chrome is not running.

I could write a native client in addition to my browser based client, but that's double the work.  (Tripple the work if you bother with a native window's client vs. just OSX but who would do that?)

Comment: Yes its possible (not sure how) GMail and Stackoverflow Chat can make growl type boxes appear

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12839128/212869 might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome can create "Desktop Notifications" See the [Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html)

It's also possible to have the notifications visible when chrome is closed providing you create a "background process". [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12839128/212869) might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome supports the text-only version of the [W3C desktop notification standard](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/). Chrome deprecated the HTML version about a year ago and will stop supporting it very soon. Any webpage viewed in Chrome and any Chrome extension can use this API.

The [Rich Notifications API](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/J4GZGvAggTU) is available to Chrome extensions and packaged apps. As of today, it's dev-channel only and is iterating rapidly. It has implementations on ChromeOS and Windows, with Mac on the way. Linux currently delegates to the W3C implementation. The API is not a 1:1 replacement of W3C HTML desktop notifications, but it does provide many layout options for common use cases.